# how to parse ics file manually in java?

Tags: java

Hi i am new to java.I wish to parse the ics (outlook calendar file) manually.With out using  third party api how to parse ics file in java?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry to start with a rebuttal, but why reinvent the wheel? especially if you don't really know how to get started? I would just use iCal4j - http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html and use your time elsewhere.

Comment: If you really want to go ahead and implement this, the first thing to do is read the spec - http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445

Answer (score 5):

Without using any third party libraries, you'll have basically have to write your own [iCalendar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) (see [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545)) parser, reproducing the work of those third party libraries. It won't be fun.

Admittedly my own experiences with [iCal4j](http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/) haven't been terribly pleasant - but I wouldn't start writing my own parser from scratch using `java.util.Date` and `java.util.Calendar`. You *may* find it's worth writing an iCalendar parser using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) to represent the various aspects ("a date", "a time" etc) as that's a much nicer API to work with than the built-in ones... but equally you may find that iCal4j is good enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer API Documentation of iCal4j
http://ical4j.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

This might help you for parsing you can refer this code :

```
{
    Properties prop = new Properties();

            prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
            final String username = "xx@xx"; //your email id
            final String password = "password"; //your password
            System.out.println(meeting);
             try {
                 Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                        }
                    });

                    MimeMessage mimeMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");
        if (calendar != null) {
                        // Another part for the calendar invite
                        MimeBodyPart invite = new MimeBodyPart();
                        invite.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
                        invite.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
                        invite.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
                        invite.setContent(calendar.toString(), "text/calendar");
                        multipart.addBodyPart(invite);
                    }

                    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

                    Transport.send(mimeMessage);
}
```